# handler keeping whole app waiting for particular period

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I am using handler to call particular method after each 6 seconds.

Code:

```
tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Logout" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

final Handler handler=new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                UpdateTask();
                handler.postDelayed(this, 6000);
            }
        }, 1000);
```

Now problem is that when i click on textview tv (which is giving me toast "Logout"), it is getting logout click after 6 seconds when messages are for read (or when the control is in UpdateTask() method.

I just wanted to get click over textview "tv" at any time i want no matter code is in UpdateTask() method.

How can i achieve this?

Please help.

**Edit:**............

```
public class Messages extends Activity {

static int cnt=0;
//protected Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_messages);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    String id = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_ID);
    String[] lst = null;
    ListView lm=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView tvNewMessages = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvNewMessages);





    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Logout" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });


    /*ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
            Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
           // Log.i("hello", "world");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    UpdateTask();
                }
            });

        }
    }, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);*/


    final Handler handler=new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            UpdateTask();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 6000);
        }
    }, 1000);

    tv.setText("Welcome " + message);

    //handler.postDelayed(new UpdateTask(),500);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.messages, menu);
    return true;
}



    public void UpdateTask() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {


        //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"update  " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        String id = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_ID);
        String[] lst = null;
        String[] lstNew = null;
        ListView lm=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView tvNewMessages = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvNewMessages);

        tv.setText("Welcome " + message);



        CallSoap cs=new CallSoap();



        lst=cs.GetMessage(id);

        lstNew=cs.GetNewMessage(id);



        final int numOfMessages=lstNew.length;  

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Call  "+lstNew.length , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Messages.this, R.layout.simple_list_item_1,FRUITS));
    //  ArrayAdapter<String> adpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Messages.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lst);


        /*for (int i=1;i<numOfMessages;i++)
        {
            tv.setText("Welcome " + i);
            //lm.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

            tv.setText("Welcome :  " + i);
        }
        */

        tvNewMessages.setText("You have "+ numOfMessages +" new messages");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Messages.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lst){
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                if(position<numOfMessages){
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    }
                else
                {
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                }
                return v;
            }
        };

        lm.setAdapter(adpt);

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Call  "+ex.getMessage() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try                 `handler.post(this, 6000);` without *Delayed*